# Weblogic - Log outbound calls from webapplication

Tags: java, weblogic

I am working on a web application, which is deployed to weblogic cluster. Upon user invoking an action in jsp, at the server side we make an outbouond call (with 2-way ssl) to an external service. This service returns me some data, which we send to the client side for rendering on UI. This flow is working as fine.

Outbound request for 2-way SSL are made from a utility class within the application, using java.net.URLConnection. However, upon checking the access.log for weblogic, I don't see these outbounds call logs in the access logs.

Now, business has Access log monitoring software in place, to monitor specific urls/reponse code  and alert IT team if the number of non-200 responses crosses some threshold.

So, the challenge I am having currently is, how to log the outbound request's url & response status to the access log of weblogic server. I have been googling over the net, but couldn't find anything so far which can suggest how to go about it. I am new to weblogic, so not sure if this is possible OOTB or I need to write some custom code for this.

Need advice from weblogic experts out there. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Weblogic only traces incoming http/s requests in its access logs. Your application is responsible for logging its own outbound requests in its own logs. Do not log your entries in weblogic's logs.